# How to declare shared array in constructor by Julia?

Tags: julia

How can I use `SharedArray` in Constructors? 
I have this code:

```
@everywhere mutable struct DDFC{T <: Real}
     n::Int64
     m::Int64
     f_valueN::SharedArray{Float64,2}
     f_policy::SharedArray{Float64,2}
end

@everywhere function DDFC(;α = 0.3,β = 0.5)
    f_valueN = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    f_policy = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    n= 2
    m=3
    DDFC(α, β,f_valueN, f_policy, n, m)

end
```

but by running `ddfc = DDFC()` I got this error:

`MethodError: no method matching DDFC(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Type{SharedArray{Float64,2}}, ::Type{SharedArray{Float64,2}}, ::Int64, ::Int64)`
how can I use sharedarray here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? And the error you have pasted is about a type `RBC` that is not included in your pasted example? I would expect the example you give to error as `n not defined` as your definition of the DDFC constructor with keyword args you define n & m after you use them.

Comment: I correct it, I want to declare shared array by constructor and use it every where of my program by `ddfc.f_policy` or something like that.

Comment: Try pasting your code into a new terminal. You will get a different error to what you have pasted.

Answer (score 1):

To help you go ahead I here give you a correction of your code that works (please note the differences):

```
@everywhere mutable struct DDFC{T <: Real}
     n::Int64
     m::Int64
     f_valueN::SharedArray{Float64,2}
     f_policy::SharedArray{Float64,2}
end

@everywhere function DDFC(;α = 0.3,β = 0.5)
    n= 2
    m=3
    f_valueN = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    f_policy = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    DDFC{Float64}(n, m, f_valueN, f_policy)
end
```

Now running `ddfc = DDFC()` works, but this code is useless, as Alexander Morley commented, as it is not clear what you want to achieve and `T` type is not used in your `struct` anyway. In particular observe that I add `{Float64}` in the call to `DDFC` in the outer constructor (this was probably your problem).

Comment: If Sharedarray is 2-dim and each elements is `Tuple` how should I declare it?

Answer (score 1):

```
@everywhere mutable struct DDFC{T <: Real}
     n::Int64
     m::Int64
     f_valueN::SharedArray{T,2}
     f_policy::SharedArray{T,2}
end

@everywhere function DDFC(;α = 0.3,β = 0.5, n=2, m=2)
    f_valueN = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    f_policy = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    DDFC(n, m, f_valueN, f_policy)
end
```

OR

```
@everywhere mutable struct DDFC{T <: Real}
     α::Float64
     β::Float64
     n::Int64
     m::Int64
     f_valueN::SharedArray{T,2}
     f_policy::SharedArray{T,2}
end

@everywhere function DDFC(;α = 0.3,β = 0.5, n=2, m=2)
    f_valueN = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    f_policy = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n, m)
    DDFC(α, β, n, m, f_valueN, f_policy)
end
```

Should both work, depending on what you are trying to do. FYI, this issue has nothing to do with `SharedArray`s but just on how you are defining/calling your constructors.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as in outer constructor you call `DDFC` which is undefined as I have noted below.

Comment: This is true. Though my guess would be the T is supposed to be `eltype` of the SharedArray anyway (as corrected).

Comment: Probably yes :).

Comment: Actually, it's a piece of my code, I parallelised my code and realise my running time is awful and memory allocation is too larger than sequential. so I tried to do it, and my memory now is a little better

Comment: If Sharedarray is 2-dim and each elements is `Tuple` how should I declare it?

Comment: If you have a new question you should post it another one. As it happens I recommend you have a careful read through of https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types and https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors first. If (afterwards) you have any *specific* areas of confusion then go ahead and post another Q on SO :)